# How do I create a structure for a dynamic SQL query?

Tags: sql, json, go

In my **Golang** application I make SQL request to the database. Usually, in the SQL query, I specify the columns that I want to get from the table and create a structure based on it. You can see an example of the working code below.

**QUESTION**:

What should I do if I don't know the number and name of columns in the table? For example, I make the SQL request like `SELECT * from filters;` instead of  `SELECT FILTER_ID, FILTER_NAME FROM filters;`. How do I create a structure in this case?

```
var GetFilters = func(responseWriter http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    rows, err := database.ClickHouse.Query("SELECT * FROM filters;"); if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    defer rows.Close()

    columns, err := rows.Columns(); if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    filters := make([]interface{}, len(columns))

    for i, _ := range columns {
        filters[i] = new(sql.RawBytes)
    }

    for rows.Next() {
        if err = rows.Scan(filters...); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
    }

    utils.Response(responseWriter, http.StatusOK, filters)
}
```

Comment: http://go-database-sql.org/varcols.html

Comment: @AndrewW.Phillips thank you for this link! I was trying to adapt my code. Can you check my post again, please? Right now I have such error: `sql: Scan error on column index 5, name "FILTER_VALUES": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []string into type *sql.RawBytes`. Do you have any ideas about how I can to fix this problem with data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, finally I found the solution. As you can see from the code below first I make SQL request where I do not specify the name of the columns. Then I take information about columns by `ColumnTypes()` function. This function returns column information such as column type, length and nullable. Next I will learn the name and type of columns, fill interface with these data:

```
for i, column := range columns {
    object[column.Name()] = reflect.New(column.ScanType()).Interface()
    values[i] = object[column.Name()]
}
```

The full code which I use looks like this:

```
var GetFilters = func(responseWriter http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request) {
    rows, err := database.ClickHouse.Query("SELECT * FROM table_name;"); if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    defer rows.Close()

    var objects []map[string]interface{}

    for rows.Next() {
        columns, err := rows.ColumnTypes(); if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        values := make([]interface{}, len(columns))

        object := map[string]interface{}{}

        for i, column := range columns {
            object[column.Name()] = reflect.New(column.ScanType()).Interface()
            values[i] = object[column.Name()]
        }

        if err = rows.Scan(values...); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        objects = append(objects, object)
    }

    utils.Response(responseWriter, http.StatusOK, objects)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the USER_TAB_COLUMNS table to get the list of columns in the executing table query store it an array or collection. later execute the query and Scan the columns that you already know from the previous Query.

Comment: Can you check my post again, please? I use the logic which you described but I have a problem with the data type. Right now I have such error: `sql: Scan error on column index 5, name "FILTER_VALUES": unsupported Scan, storing driver.Value type []string into type *sql.RawBytes`. Do you have any ideas about how I can to fix this problem with the data type.